# Node js hazelcast connection is not working in kubernets 3.12.4

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, hazelcast

I'm trying to connect Hazelcast server with version : 3.12.4.
With IP and port number it's working perfectly fine but when I use service name it's not working in NodeJS same approach is working in java. Java code sample

```
<network>
    <discovery-strategies>
        <discovery-strategy enabled="true"
            class="com.hazelcast.kubernetes.HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategy">
            <properties>
                <property name="service-name">hazelcast</property>
                <property name="namespace">default</property>
            </properties>
        </discovery-strategy>
    </discovery-strategies>
    <smart-routing>true</smart-routing>
    <redo-operation>true</redo-operation>
    <connection-timeout>90000</connection-timeout>
    <connection-attempt-period>100</connection-attempt-period>
    <connection-attempt-limit>0</connection-attempt-limit>
</network>`
```

But in case of not it's not working

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/hazelcast-client/v/3.12.3

also tried with other versions.

**Bellow code is working in node js hazelcast-client : 3.12.3**

```
import { Client, Config, Predicates } from 'hazelcast-client';
    const config = new Config.ClientConfig();
    config.properties = {
      'hazelcast.client.heartbeat.timeout': 10000,
      'hazelcast.client.invocation.retry.pause.millis': 4000,
      'hazelcast.client.invocation.timeout.millis': 180000,
      'hazelcast.invalidation.reconciliation.interval.seconds': 50,
      'hazelcast.invalidation.max.tolerated.miss.count': 15,
      'hazelcast.invalidation.min.reconciliation.interval.seconds': 60
    };
    config.groupConfig.name = '';
    config.networkConfig.addresses.push('HOST_WITH_PORT');
    config.networkConfig.smartRouting = true;
    config.networkConfig.connectionTimeout = 6000;
    config.networkConfig.connectionAttemptPeriod = 4000;
    config.networkConfig.connectionAttemptLimit = 3;
      const client = await Client.newHazelcastClient(config);
```

If anyone can help how can I connect without host and port number using `hazelcast-client:3.12.4`.

Comment: I am not good at Kubernetes. However, I know how the client works. It does not have a special plugin for Kubernetes.  As answered by gohm'c, you can try using DNS. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns. So if the client is outside the namespace you should resolve `my-service.my-ns` via DNS otherwise you can use just `my-service`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DNS](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html) module to resolve the service name `hazelcast.default` and push the IP.

Comment: : Unable to connect to any of the following addresses: 10.107.62.3:5701, 10.107.62.3:5702, 10.107.62.3:5703
    at new IllegalStateError (/home/node/app/node_modules/hazelcast-client/lib/HazelcastError.js:73:28)

Getting this error it's not working

Comment: Can you post the k8s spec you used to run hazelcast to your question.